# apache-tomcat-8.0.22; Error occurred in initializing VM java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : java/lang/Object

Tags: windows-7, java, tomcat, jre

I have reinstalled JRE with latest version JRE1.8.0_45 .

Whenever I try to run Tomcat :startup.bat this error occurs .

Installation of JRE done with Oracle online installer and was perfect.

JAVA_HOME is also set properly.

Please suggest what could be the issue.

Comment: Maybe you need jdk not jre. Also check this http://serverfault.com/questions/130689/tomcat-6-0-service-does-not-start-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure PATH variable is set correctly. Also you need to have the classpath settings accurate for it to load necessary jars.

> NoClassDefFoundError

usually refers to class not found when the java command is issued. In your case it might be tomcat is not able to execute the command inside bat file due to missing values in **classpath**

Answer (score 0):

The tip given above by Dan worked.When I set the JRE path to that of JDK (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre) then Tomcat started working.